# Extract current running stage from dvc

Tags: python, machine-learning, workflow, mlops, dvc

I'm conducting an experiment using 'dvc repro -f', where multiple stages are executed according to the dvc.yaml configuration. For instance:

```
Stages:
 Training:
   foreach:
    -cycle: 0
    -cycle: 1
    -cycle: 2
   do:
    cmd:
     python train.py
 Selection:
   foreach:
    -cycle: 0
    -cycle: 1
    -cycle: 2
   do:
    cmd:
     python train.py
```

During the execution of each stage, such as the training stage at cycle 0, I aim to extract its stage name, like 'Training_0', within a Python program and during selection stage it should be Selection_0. I'm seeking a method to extract this information either while the stage is being executed or just before its execution begins. i tried using the dvc.api but the api does not return the current stage that is running. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it to the `train.py` as an arg:

```
stages:
 Training:
   foreach:
    -cycle: 0
    -cycle: 1
    -cycle: 2
   do:
    cmd:
     python train.py "Training-${item.cycle}"
 Selection:
   foreach:
    -cycle: 0
    -cycle: 1
    -cycle: 2
   do:
    cmd:
     python train.py "Selection-${item.cycle}"
```

Would something like this work for you? It would be a nice addition to have this in the `dvc.api` and probably as an ENV variable. It feels it should be straightforward to add. Feel free to help us do this - all contributions are welcome and we can help :)

Comment: This might be a quick work around and maybe helpful but I was wondering if there exists something right now in the dvc pipeline that can help us. I do observe that when i run the flow with dvc repro -f. Before execution of a stage I get an output on console that says Running Stage "Training@0". Where does the dvc get this from? and is it stored somewhere ?

Comment: It comes from this https://github.com/iterative/dvc/blob/main/dvc/stage/run.py#L100 . To add a new env var with a stage name - it should be as simple as modifying / expanding this - https://github.com/iterative/dvc/blob/main/dvc/stage/run.py#L41 . If env var is exposed, `dvc.api` helper can be added to read it.

Comment: Might be a good idea. I will give it a shot. Thank you